# Why does python requests return 401?

Tags: api, python-requests

Why does this python code return 401 request status code w

```
import requests

url = "https://localtonet.com/api/GetAuthTokens"

def send_request():
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer h<REDACTED>E'}

    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return resp

print (send_request())
```

The official [documentation](https://localtonet.com/api/index.html) states that the request should be similar to this

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localtonet.com/api/GetAuthTokens' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer h<REDACTED>E'
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't think so, according to [swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. You just need to replace `<mytoken>` with an actual token that you must obtain by providing your username and password to some interface/API.

HTTP status code 401 signifies `Unauthorized` which basically means your authorization credentials are invalid.

Looking at the API you are trying to access, I found this on their website:

> You can get ApiKey from https://localtonet.com/Dashboard

Try logging in to the dashboard to see if you can obtain a token from there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i am using my token but i removed it from the code

Comment: Do you also get `401` when you try the `curl` example?

Comment: yes i tried the curl command and got `401`

Comment: Then either: 1. Your token is invalid. - 2. Your token is valid but is not authorized to be used with that API.